# Find a value in a field of a cell array of structures

Tags: matlab, octave, cell-array

Having defined the GNU/Octave cell array

```
dict = 
{
  [1,1] =
    scalar structure containing the fields:
      id = integers
      vl = ... -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...
  [1,2] =
    scalar structure containing the fields:
      id = positive integers
      vl = 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
  [1,3] =
    scalar structure containing the fields:
      id = negative integers
      vl = -1, -2, -3, -4, ...
}
```

how to find (in Octave code, without looping!) the structs that have a given value in a field, say, those containing `'integer'` in the `id` field, or `-1` in the `vl` field.

Update: The command would operate like `find(dict,'vl','-1')`, returning `1, 3`, or `1 0 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible implementation of the search function would look like:

```
function arrayvalues = findinfield(mycellarray, inputfield, outputfield, fieldvalue)

  positions = ~cellfun(@isempty, regexp({[mycellarray{:}].(inputfield)}, fieldvalue));
  arrayvalues = {[mycellarray{positions}].(outputfield)};

end
```

For an exact matching add `^` and `$` to the beginning and end, respectively, of the regular expression.

Use cases:

```
findinfield(dict, "id", "vl", "integers")
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = ... -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...}
  [1,2] = 1, 2, 3, 4, ...}
  [1,3] = -1, -2, -3, -4, ...}
}

findinfield(dict, "id", "vl", "^integers$")
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = 1, 2, 3, 4, ...}
}

findinfield(dict, "id", "vl", "negative")
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = -1, -2, -3, -4, ...}
}
```

Comment: You can use dynamic field referencing, where your field is stored in a string `fieldName` passed as an argument: `arrayvalues = {[mycellarray{positions}].(fieldName)};`

Comment: Nice, @gnovice !!